# LocalDateTime in seconds

Tags: java

I have a String in the format of `hh:mm:ss`. It is a duration of a telephone call.

I want to get the duration of that call in seconds.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStr, formatter);
```

How can I get the duration in seconds from the LocalDateTime?

Comment: Don't make a LocalDateTime object out of it. It will work as in baaos answer, but it's a very odd train of thought, because you are talking about a duration and you put it into an object that is supposed to hold a fixed time at a certain day, month and year. assylas shows you a better way, even though the method is still called "toSecondOfDay()" which may cause confusion for people trying to read your code. Which is why I would go Okx way instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no date component, so you can simply use a `LocalTime`, although ***`LocalTime` is not really designed to represent a duration***:

```
String input = "01:52:27";
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input);
int seconds = time.toSecondOfDay();
```

Note that this will only work for durations up to `23:59:59`.

---

A ***better approach would be to use the `Duration` class*** - note that it will also cope with longer durations:

```
//convert first to a valid Duration representation
String durationStr = input.replaceAll("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "PT$1H$2M$3S");
Duration duration = Duration.parse(durationStr);
int seconds = duration.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Don't use a type designed to represent a moment, to represent a duration. A movie is an hour-and-a-half in length, not half-past-one-in-the-morning.

Comment: I agree with that and would recommend the `Duration` approach. I've edited to clarify that point.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to convert it to `LocalDateTime`, we can get the seconds straight from the string.

Try splitting it by colons, and getting the last element.

Or, if you're looking for the *total* seconds, multiply each part accordingly:

```java
String time = "10:15:34";

String[] sections = time.split(":");

int seconds = Integer.parseInt(sections[2]);

int totalSeconds = 
    (Integer.parseInt(sections[0]) * 60 * 60) +
    (Integer.parseInt(sections[1]) * 60) +
    (Integer.parseInt(sections[2]));

System.out.println("Seconds: " + seconds);
System.out.println("Total seconds: " + totalSeconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there's something build in, but the following should do the job:

```
private long getSecondDuration(LocalDateTime t) {
    long h = t.getHour();
    long m = t.getMinute();
    long s = t.getSecond();
    return  (h * 3600) + (m * 60) + s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), test if the `String` matches a regular expression pattern (like three sets of digits separated by colons) and build a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(timeStr);
if (m.matches()) {
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
    Duration d = Duration.ofHours(hours).plusMinutes(minutes).plusSeconds(seconds);
    System.out.println(d.getSeconds());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LocalDateTime` is a `Temporal` and these represent a point in time, not a duration.

Although "1:30:00" can be interpreted as a point and as a duration, the semantics are different.

- As a point in time: "Half past one in the morning"
- As a duration: "An hour and a half"

One reason this is important is that "25:30:02" is a valid duration, but not a valid time-of-day.

Java 8 has a `java.time.Duration` class.

If you can rely on your input strings being valid, it's easy to split them:

```
String[] parts = durationAsString.split(":");
Duration duration = Duration
    .ofHours(Long.parseLong(parts[0]))
    .plusMinutes(Long.parseLong(parts[1]))
    .plusSeconds(Long.parseLong(parts[2]));
```

(If you can't rely on the input being valid, either pre-validate with a regex, or add code to handle `parts.length != 3` and parse exceptions from `parseLong`)

Check the Javadoc for `Duration` to see what you can do with it. One method is `getSeconds()` which gives you the total duration in seconds.

You can also use a `Duration` along with `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime` etc. - there are methods to add a `Duration` to a time to get a new time; to subtract one `Temporal` from another to get a `Duration` and so on.

It's possible that `Duration` is more sophisticated than you need. If you really just need to convert "01:30:10" to seconds, there's nothing wrong with doing the maths yourself:

```
String[] parts = durationAsString.split(":");
long seconds = 
    Long.parseLong(parts[0]) * 60 * 60 +
    Long.parseLong(parts[1]) * 60 +
    Long.parseLong(parts[2]);
```